# Using constructor in a child class throws an error

Tags: c#

I've been studying how to use inherited classes in **`C#`**. I have no clue whatsoever as to why my code in invalid.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have one class (`Child`) that inherits from another (`Parent`).  Each class should have its own constructor. The error reads:

> << CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
>   << formal parameter 'isOpen' of 'Parent.Parent(bool)'

```
public class Parent
    {
        internal bool IsOpen;

        public Parent(bool isOpen)
        {
            this.IsOpen = isOpen;
        }
    }

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public Child(bool isOpen)
        {
            this.IsOpen = isOpen;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it down to the parent via the `base` keyword:

```
public class Parent
{
    internal bool IsOpen;

    public Parent(bool isOpen)
    {
        this.IsOpen = isOpen;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(bool isOpen)
        : base(isOpen)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Videtutorial I'm using has failed to include that information. Thanks! On a side  note: I want my field to be accessible from the class only and be inheritable. Is `internal` modificator good here?

Comment: `protected` means the member can be accessed from itself and anything that inherits it.

Comment: @menteith No, that's `protected`. `internal` means anything in that assembly can see it -- not often useful.

Comment: Thanks, so I go with `protected`. BTW, what's wrong with my question? I think it is on topic yet it has been downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the constructor of the base class (`Parent`) in your subclass:

```
public class Parent
{
    internal bool IsOpen;

    public Parent(bool isOpen)
    {
        this.IsOpen = isOpen;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(bool isOpen) : base(isOpen)
    {
    }
}
```

This also removes the need for you to set `IsOpen` again in the constructor of `Child`.